# Apostol 4.4 exercise 10 . Proof and help needed

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Ok so the problem says:

> Let $b$ denote a fixed positive integer. Prove the following statement by induction: For every integer nonnegative integer $n$, there exist nonnegative integers $q$ and $r$ such that
>
> 1. $n = qb + r$
> 2. $r<b$

My initial guess was the fact that every number is either odd or even and from that we can conclude that :
$n=2q + 1$ or $n=2q$

But what if $b$ is some other number other than two?I know for fact it can be done for any $b$ and any $n$ but I am not able to prove it.

Any suggestion would be very welcome. Thanks in advance

Comment: See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division#Proof) or open any elementary number theory book.

Comment: I understand this.But slight question.Which book would you recommend?

Comment: I don't know, to be honest. Elementary number theory is not my cup of tea, but for this particular question any book should do. Or Google, for that matter.

Comment: http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~benchow/DivisionTheorem.pdf       It is a good answer for all future troopers.I found it very nice.

Answer (score 2):

Let $S = \{ n - ba: a\in\mathbb{Z}, n - ba > 0\}$.  Then $S$ is a nonvoid subset of the positive integers. By induction, it has a least element $r$. This is the element you seek to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Proof 1** $\ $  Show $\,r = $ least element of $\ n\!+\!b\,\Bbb Z\,\cap\, \Bbb N\,$ (uses Least Number Principle / well-ordered)

**Proof 2** $\ $ (complete  induction) $ $  If $\,n < b$ then $\, n = 0\cdot b + n.\,$ Else $\,n-b\in \Bbb N\ $ so, by induction, $\ n-b = qb+r,\, r< b,\ $ so $\  n = (q\!+\!1)b + r.$

**Remark** $\ $ Proof $2$, constructivized, yields the following algorithm to compute $\,(q,r)$

```
        div(n,b)  :=  if  n < b  then  (0,n)  else  div(n-b,b) + (1,0)
```